# List has no rows for assignment

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

Can any one help me in solving this error:List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Class at line :

```
qName = [select Row_Id__c, Name from Ccon__c where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')].Row_Id__c;
```

Test Class line :

```
Controller  controller1  = new Controller(sc1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This mean your query is returning no result (So the list is empty and then when casting into an Sobject there is not item to take).

```
qName = [select Row_Id__c, Name from Ccon__c where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')].Row_Id__c;
```

I would do it this way (to make sure in any case I will get value from my query if my ID is valid):

```
Id tempID = null;
if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null)
{
    tempId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
}
else{ //Error management
}

List<Ccon__c> recordsToProcess = new List<Ccon__c>();

if(tempID != null)
{
    recordsToProcess = [select Row_Id__c, Name from Ccon__c where Id = :tempID];
}
else{ //Error management
}


//qName Declaration
if(!recordsToProcess.isEmpty())
{
    qName = recordsToProcess[0].Row_Id__c;
}
else{ //Error management
}

if(qName == null)
{
   //Error management
}
```

If you have more questions please feel free to ask. But as a best practice you might always ensure that your list is not empty before getting the record returned.

Thanks 
HqSeO